# How do I select two tables in 1 query?

Tags: mysql

I want to select two tables in one query but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried nested select but I just got sql_error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT `client`.`id` as client_id,
(SELECT `org`.`name` FROM `org`) as organization
FROM `client`
```

What is the better way to query two tables?

Here is my expected result:

```
client_id = [1,2,3,4,5]
organization = [x,y,z]
```

Comment: Is there any thing common between client and organization

Comment: Use `join`.  That is the way that SQL normally brings two tables together.

Comment: just use two queries if there's no foreign key between those two tables

Comment: what do you mean @Strawberry?

Comment: Will be useful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables

Comment: use union but the columns are have to be sam data type

Comment: There is no need to use joins or unions. 'select * from client, org' would work just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will work but it isn't what you want i think.

```
SELECT `client`.`id` as client_id, `org`.`name` as organization FROM `org`, `client`
```

This will give you a cross product of all rows in org with all rows in client. Maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT `client`.`id` as client_id, `org`.`name` as organization FROM `org` JOIN `client` ON `client`.`memberOf` = `org`.`id`
```

The **JOIN** will connect rows of both tables where column memberOf in table **client** is equal to column id in table **org**

Answer (score 0):

You should use join queries to join two or more tables. you can visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Example of the join query:

SELECT t1.name, t2.salary
  FROM employee AS t1 INNER JOIN info AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;